# create instance of custom xib class make gesture recognizer don't work

Tags: ios, swift, xib

first I create a .xib file and named it **RadioBtnView** and connect it to a custom UIView class :

```
class CheckBtnView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CheckBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkDescription: UILabel!
    
    var status = false {
        didSet {
            if status {
                CheckBtn.backgroundColor = .orange
            } else {
                CheckBtn.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    
    private func setupViews(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CheckBtnView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.frame = self.bounds
        mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]

    }
}
```

then try to add an instance of RadioBtnView programmatically in viewController and add gesture recognizer to it :

```
let radio = RadioBtnView()
scrollContainerView.addSubview(radio)
radio.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
radio.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: entry.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
radio.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 38).isActive = true
radio.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let radioGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(change(_:)))
radio.addGestureRecognizer(radioGesture)
```

but the change(_:) function doesn't respond seems like it didn't call

is this for creating the xib view programmatically or something else?

Comment: It's a good idea to post code that actually works... You appear to be working on a `CheckBtnView` class and a `RadioBtnView` class, and the code you posted is mixing them. Without more info, and details on your .xib layout, it's very possible that you are missing constraints. Add this line: `radio.backgroundColor = .green` and see if a green rectangle shows up containing your labels and button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know the reason ... I just delete `radio.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and add the `radio.frame = CGRect(x:50,y:100,width:120,height:20)`  and every think work
this seems like we can not add xib view programmatically

Comment: If you have constraints setup correctly in your .xib, you can use auto-layout.